# Using ApplicationIntent=ReadOnly with stored procedures which insert data to temp tables

Tags: sql-server, alwayson

I'm using  SQL Server 2012 AlwaysOn listener and I want to use a connection with `ApplicationIntent=ReadOnly` parameter for calling some stored procedures, and this is my question: stored procedures which insert data into temp table can use connection with `ApplicationIntent=ReadOnly` ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to [Readable Secondary Replicas](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878253.aspx)

> Note
>
> Though you cannot write data to secondary databases, you can write to
>   read-write databases on the server instance that hosts the secondary
>   replica, including user databases and system databases such as **tempdb**.

So the answer is your stored procedures will work.